# Have at least one input field as required dynamically in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have three fields i use for my search , but only one 'em is required (at least one of'em should be submited so  i tried to have a conditionned required as seen in code below , but takes no effect , as all three fields are all the time required when clicking the command button , even when one field has value . should i use jquery to resolve this on button click.

```
<h:form id="search_form">
    <p:inputText name="field1" id="field1" type="text"
    required="#{searchBean.SearchCriteria.field3==null and  searchBean.searchCriteria.field2==null}" value="#{searchBean.searchCriteria.field1}"></p:inputText>

    <p:inputText name="field2" id="field2" type="text"
    required="#{searchBean.SearchCriteria.field1==null and  searchBean.searchCriteria.field3==null}" value="#{searchBean.searchCriteria.field2}"></p:inputText>             

    <p:inputText name="field3" id="field3" type="text"
    required="#{searchBean.SearchCriteria.field1==null and  searchBean.searchCriteria.field3==null}" value="#{searchBean.searchCriteria.field3}"></p:inputText>                 

        <p:commandButton id="search_button" ajax="false"  title="#process="@form" action{#searchBean.search()}" />
 </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your bean's `search()` method run the validation , return `null` and possibly add a facesMessage if none of those fields is filled up.